# How to use ratios to find out which animal's heart beats faster

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A dogs heartbeat was recorded as 38 beats in 20 seconds. A cats heartbeat was recorded as 72 beats in 40 seconds. Which has the faster heartbeat? Find the answer using ratios.

I have tried to put this into a simple ratio 38:20:72= 40:X:Y this does not seem correct and I need help asap.

Answer (score 1):

We can measure the speed of their hearts in beats per second. As a dog has 38 heartbeats in 20 seconds, he has $\frac{38}{20}=\frac{19}{10}=1.9$ heartbeats per second. A cat has 72 beats in 40 seconds, so in one second there are $\frac{72}{40}=\frac{36}{20}=\frac{18}{10}=1.8$ heartbeats per second.

You can now see which of the animals has the faster heartbeat.

There is a shorter version, if you are not interested in the actual speeds: The dog was measured for 20 seconds; half the time of the cat's measurements. Thus, in 40 seconds, a dog would have $2*38=76$ heartbeats, which are more than the 72 of the cat, yielding the same result.

Irrelevant bonus section: 1.8 beats per second is 108 bpm, which is the speed of [No Doubt's I'm just a GIrl](http://www.tape.tv/musikvideos/No-Doubt/Just-A-Girl) and [some other songs](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~davet/music/bpm/108.html). 1.9 beats per second is 114 BPM, which is the speed of [Lovin' Spoonful's Summer in the City](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1_8909dNJ0) and [other songs](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~davet/music/bpm/114.html).